# Paged GridView Only Populates First Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have populated a GridView using the following method:

```
List<MyObject> items = new List<MyObject>();
// here I am filling the list using SQL
        PanelGridView.DataSource = items; //fill GridView with objects, this works when NOT using paging
        PanelGridView.DataBind();
```

With this, and paging disabled, I have a fully populated GridView. However, when I turn on paging, the first page is filled, but all subsequent pages are empty. How can I make sure all of the items are accounted for, and divided properly among the pages (given the page size I've specified)?

EDIT: I forgot to include this code:

```
    protected void PanelGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    PanelGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    PanelGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: What is your panels object? "items" is defined, but not panels. Can you please add the missing code?

Comment: I changed the code to avoid confusion, and forgot to change panels to items. Fixed the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you databind the grid after changing the page and also make sure to set the page index to the new page index.  This is done in the PageChanging event handler.

Comment: I'm very sorry about this, I should've included that code. I've edited the original post to show that I am doing this. Is it certain that it should be in the PageIndexChanging handler, and not the PageIndexChanged handler?

Comment: You also have to re-set the data source of the PanelGridView before redatabinding.

Comment: Why does the GridView lose the data source when you change pages?

Comment: When the form is posted back to the server the data is lost.  You could store the data into the view state so you won't have to query for it everytime (however this might not be a good idea if you have a large amount of data)

Comment: It'd probably be better for me to just re-assign the data source. It just seems silly to have to do this when I already obtained the data in the first place.

Comment: I just recalled the function that originally populated the GridView. From my understanding, this function would have populated the GridView with the entire list starting at that page, but it seems to be working. So I'm not really sure why that works, but it works...though it does include the data source setting and binding, so I just did the page index setting as well and it works. Thanks for your help!